# Excel plotting many data sets each with their own x-axis values on the same graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I know how to plot each data set so that they all show up on the same chart together but the way I'm doing it is very labour intensive and will take a long time to do this for all sets of data (50+ data sets). My data looks like this [the time is each data sets x-axis and columns A and B are results from different trials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STr3k.png). The current method I'm using requires me to manually select the x values and y values for every set, 1 time for data A and 1 time for data B. If there is no easier way to do this then I'll keep doing this but this means I'm selecting data to put into a plot twice for each of the over 50 trials. Any suggestions are appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2010, I would suggest you [install Power Query add-ins](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

Then select your data, go to Power Query tab > From Table/Range.

Select all the columns of Time > Right click to choose Upivot Columns.

[image]

Descend sort Attirbute column, and move Attirbute and Values columns to the far left

Click File > Close & Load to one worksheet, set the format of Value columns to be time. Select the columns that you need to insert chart.

[image]